# A question about diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

For which $x$ is $$M=\begin{pmatrix}4&0&-2\\x&5&4\\0&0&5\end{pmatrix}$$ diagonalizable?

I know a matrix which is diagonalizable can be written in the form $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ But I don't know what property these kinds of matrices all have? Distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: use to have an idea: [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigen+system+%7B%7B4%2C+0%2C+-2%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+5%2C+4%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+0%2C+5%7D%7D ]

Comment: Matrices are diagonalisable if they have distinct eigenvectors.

Comment: @BlackAdder That is not necessary

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 is it not? Perhaps the dimension of the eigenspace must match that of the matrix then? Are they not the same?

Comment: @BlackAdder A matrix is diagonalizable iff the dimension of eigenspace = the multiplicity of eigenvalue in the characteristic polynomial for all eigenvalues.  (This is assuming the characteristic polynomial splits in whatever field we're working over.)

Answer (score 2):

For your given matrix it is easy to see, that the eigenvalues of $M$ are $4,5$ and $5$, and this holds independent of $x$

Thus $M$ is diagonalizable if $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Eig}(5) = 2$. To calculate the eigenspace to $5$ you have to solve $A\nu =5\nu$ for $\nu$, which is equivalent to

$$A\nu=5\nu\Longleftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}-1&0&-2\\x&0&4\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot \nu = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

One eigenvector $\nu_1$ is clearly given by $\left(0,1,0\right)^T$. A second linear unindependent eigenvector $\nu_2$ is given by $\left(2,0,-1\right)^T$ *iff* $x=2$.